# Page margins on a PHP generated Word document (using fopen)

Tags: php, ms-word, doc

I recently posted a question on how to generate a .doc file without using the COM object - I had some great replies (thank you!) but unfortunately I need the document to be compatible with the old .doc format and not .docx since we're all using Office 2003 here, without the compatibility plugin.

I have the following code which generates a very basic document, but one that will probably do the job, the problem is the header image is very large (and essential) and won't fit in unless I lower the page margin... I tried changing the margin and padding of HTML/Body to 0 but had no luck unfortunately:

```
$fp = fopen("test.doc", 'w+');
$str = "<html><body><img src=\"http://url/header_image.png\">

    <B>Content</B></body></html>";

fwrite($fp, $str);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: You do realize that you are **not** generating a Word .DOC document, but a regular HTML file?

Comment: Valid point, and yes :( Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You are not actually creating a Word file, just a HTML file that Word is formatting using its own internal renderer.

You may as well just distribute them as `html` files.

The only benefit I can think of is that you only have to target versions of Word rather than all browsers.

Comment: Thanks, you're not wrong, but unfortunately it's a requirement that they're generated as word documents since it makes them a lot easier to archive and print, in a way that's familiar for the users :/

Answer (score 2):

A couple years late, but it might help someone else:
http://sunsetsoftware.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-create-word-document-with-html.html

```
@page Section1{
    size: 29.7cm 21cm;
    margin: 2cm 2cm 2cm 2cm;
    mso-page-orientation: landscape;
    mso-footer:f1;
}
```

That is the interesting section. To make it portrait:

```
@page Section1{
    size: 21cm 29.7cm;
    margin: 2cm 2cm 2cm 2cm;
    mso-page-orientation: portrait;
    mso-footer:f1;
}
```